# Detecting form change get id

Tags: forms, select, parent

I am trying to get the form id when an option in a drop down is selected:

HTML

```
<form id="test">
     <select id="option1">
      <option id="opt1">Hello</option>
     </select>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$("#test").change(function(){

     var formid=$("test").parent("form");
     alert(formid);

});
```

The output in the alert is "object object". I have also tried closest which gives the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#test").change(function(){

     var formid=$("test").parent("form").attr('id');
     alert(formid);
});
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice.
Your selector is grabbing the form itself.  

Instead, use something like this.  
`$("select").change(function(){  
         var formid=$(this).parent("form").attr('id');  
         alert(formid);  

    });`